# Handling build type and productFlavors for firestore on firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-productflavors, android-build-type

I have an android application in which we are using buildType and productFlavors both. Currently we have three buildType (QA,RC And Production) and have fifteen different productFlavors (com.companyname.employee.general,com.companyname.employee.domain1,com.companyname.employee.domain2.. etc). We are separating different app based on different flavour which have unique Application ID (generalQa,generalRc,generalProduction ,domain1Qa,domain1RC...etc).

But right now we have not  separated anything on firebase and receiving all data of every buildType and flavour in one singleProject (have registered different app for different Application ID . Mainly we are using firebase for analytics and crashlytics). But now we are going to use firestore and for this I want to  separate out this on my buildType which can support all the buildFlavour.

Can anyone please suggest the best way to do this in android and also how to structure this in android file system?